# Tor 7.0 or 6.5.2 not starting at all after Win 10 Update an even after new installing

Tags: windows, startup

last night a windows update KB4022716 was installed automatically but now Tor won´t start at all. A windows failure dialog pops always up that Tor ist nor working properly and will be closed.

Unfortunately I havn´t used Tor for the last two weeks so I am not sure but assume that the problem could be the Win update.

Even deleting the tor folder and installing in a new folder doenst help with the actual 7.x version of tor. Also the older version 6.5.2 doesn´t start after new installation anymore.

[image]

1. How can I get some information what could be the problem? Where do I found a log with inportant information about the possible problem?
2. If anyone know this failure help would be apreciated.

Thanks.

Sam

Update:
In the windows logs I found the following which ioccurs several times there:

Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: firefox.exe, Version: 45.9.0.6241, Zeitstempel: 0x00000000
Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: cmdshim32.dll, Version: 10.0.1.6223, Zeitstempel: 0x58fbd220
Ausnahmecode: 0xc0000005
Fehleroffset: 0x0000135b
ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0x894
Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01d2f23c1718c742
Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung: C:\Internet\TorBrowser\Browser\firefox.exe
Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmdshim32.dll
Berichtskennung: 5339f314-9801-4b86-883d-29c0a77e0e4c
Vollständiger Name des fehlerhaften Pakets: 
Anwendungs-ID, die relativ zum fehlerhaften Paket ist:

Does this information help, I am unsure. Any tips?

Comment: The Windows Application Event Logs should have information about the crash. If you could provide the contents of the event log that should help show where it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Your COMODO anti-virus is performing [DLL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) to spy on your usage of Tor Browser.

`cmdshim32.dll`, where the fault is happening, is part of COMODO. This needs to be fixed from their side.

**N.B.:** [Stop using anti-virus](https://github.com/epidemics-scepticism/writing/blob/master/guide.md#anti-virus) if you have anonymity or privacy requirements.